# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-day-picker/dist/style.css'

Tags: react-day-picker

this is mistake In in path check node_mdoule there is path of style.css in the /lib folder not in /dist so import like this
Before .....

`import 'react-day-picker/dist/style.css'`   this is wrong

Answer (score 0):

this is mistake In in path check node_mdoule there is path of style.css in the /lib folder not in /dist so import like this
Before .....

`import 'react-day-picker/dist/style.css'`    this is right, will work